# how to rename play framework 1.2.5 application project

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-1.x

i have a play framework application project and i want to rename it.I have tried to rename the directory,but it didn't work. When i open project in eclipse, there is no change in my project name. Anyone know how to rename it? Thanks for any response to my question, sorry for my bad english

update : i have tried to edit application name in .project file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>LKPP</name> -- i change name to jcommon-core-test-1.3
    <comment></comment>
```

when i run `play eclipsify`, it change again to LKPP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of a play project is configured in the configuration file `conf/application.conf` inside the project directory.

Therefore to change the name of a play project, search for the line `application.name=` (it should be one of the first lines) and change it to whatever you want and run `play eclipsify` again. The name should be changed in eclipse now as well (Maybe you have to delete and reimport the project again so it finally works).